# 401.0 - Unauthorized - MVC App with IIS 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2003

I've got an MVC app that normally works fine, but on a particular server, it's returning a 401.0 "The authenticated user does not have access to a resource needed to process the request" error.

Normally it works like this:

1. User logs into a separate application, gets a user ID and token, clicks a link into this application. User ID and token go into the URL.
2. User gets into my application with Anonymous auth, and then in our LogonAuthorize filter, we get the ID and token from the query string to authenticate the user.

I have logging in the filter, and I can see the user getting authenticated. So, they're making it at least that far. However, instead of the page they're supposed to see, there's a 401.0 Unauthorized error from IIS.

Things I have tried:

- Giving IUSR access to the directory
- Running mirate.exe (it's an Entity Framework app)
- Removing all [Authorize] attributes in the solution... I know that we make it as far as the Initialize() event of my BaseController object. We don't seem to make it into the specific controller actions, such as Home/Index, which inherits BaseController. I don't see any logging after BaseController.Initialize().
- Giving Network Service access to the directory
- Switching the App Pool from Integrated to Classic (I get a blank screen instead of a 401.0 error, which is odd. Same authentication stuff in the logs.)
- Using a local user account instead of Network Service with the app pool, giving that account access to the directory
- Setting different accounts to be used by "Anonymous"
- Rebuilding and redeploying the app (several times)
- Different authentication schemes: Turning on Windows auth gives a 401.1, turning off all of them gives a 401.2
- Making sure Global.asax is in the right place
- aspnet_regiis -i
- Tearing all my hair out (counterproductive)

I set up a tracing rule for this error, and I have a trace, but I have no idea how to read it. I would paste it here, but it's a pretty long XML file.

The error comes from module ManagedPipelineHandler, notification ExecuteRequestHandler, handler System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler, with error code 0x00000000.

One detail: This server is configured to use port 90 instead of port 80. I'm not sure why that would cause problems, but maybe it would?

One other detail: The app in question is running as an application in a virtual directory underneath the "main" application, which is configured as the root website.

One new detail: This server is Windows Server 2008 R2, and was upgraded from Windows Server 2003. I believe something in the upgrade process may account for the issue, as none of the "usual suspect" solutions to this type of problem have helped.

Comment: Is there any cookie sharing OR Single-signOn in the application?

Comment: How you are checking accessibility? I mean do you have checked hosted application from same machine OR from different machines? Is same version of MVC and .net installed on both servers?????

Comment: See the answer I posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have found the solution but seeking clarification why it worked. This can be one of the scenario.

Seems your website/web application was hosted through specific user credentials that was expired. Next time when you remove & add windows authentication through new credentials or application pass through it worked.

I face similar situation in one of our test web application that is hosted using specific user Path Credentials. Each time user password is changed/expired. Web application stops working.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Windows authenticates first with Kerberos.  Next it attempts other authentication methods.  Your requirement was NTLM.  Turning off all but Windows Authentication forced the application to attempt NTLM which succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the solution here was to turn on Windows auth and turn off every other form of authentication, which is counterintuitive. But there you go... that's what made it work.

If someone wants to post an answer explaining WHY that was the answer for me, I'll award them the bounty.